# how to get the third element (from the beginning and from the end) in a map c++

Tags: c++11, stdmap

I want to access the third element(both in forward and reverse order) without iterating the map.

```
int main() {
map<int,int>mp;
vector<int>v={1,4,2,5,4,2,5,7,6,9,7,9,8};
for(int i=0;i<v.size();++i)
{
    mp[v[i]]++;
}
return 0;
```

}

here the expected output would be 4 2 and 7 2.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This code only builds your `map`.

Comment: Are you required to use a std::map for this? A trimmed priority queue or heap-managed array would give the two answers without iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [std::advance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) function, but note that the map container is not designed for random access so even if you avoid iterating yourself for performance reasons, it is what happens under the hood anyway giving linear time complexity.

```
// forward iterator
auto it_fwd = mp.begin();
std::advance(it_fwd, 2);    // go to the 3rd item from the beggining

// backward iterator
auto it_bwd = mp.rbegin();
std::advance(it_bwd, 2);    // go to the 3rd item from the end

std::cout << it_fwd->first << ':' << it_fwd->second << '\n';
std::cout << it_bwd->first << ':' << it_bwd->second << '\n';
```